# Low quality figures using RMD to create latex docs

Tags: r, pdf, graph, r-markdown

Good morning,

I have decided to try RMarkdown to create short white papers that I will be updating regularly.  The rmd code extracts Fed data, organizes it, and then creates graphs that are placed alongside some short commentary about them.

My question is about the output.  The figures created within Rstudio are crisp and what I wanted; the pdf output should the lines as thicker and much less crisp.

My code chunk is below. I've tried changing the dpi at the top of the chunk, but that has not changed the pdf output.

Any ideas about getting the same crisp lines within RStudio onto pdf using Rmarkdown?

Thanks!

````
```{r echo=FALSE,dpi=600,message=FALSE}

# Create caption
mycaption<- "Source: FredII - Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis"

# Wrap caption 120 characters:
mycaption <- paste0(strwrap(mycaption, 120), sep="", collapse="\n")


# Create Plot
ggplot(data=dt2,aes(x=date,y=value,color=name,linetype=name))+
  geom_line(size=0.7)+
  labs(x="",y="Interest Rates",
       title="Comparing Interest Rates by Source/Maturity",
       caption=mycaption       ) +
  guides(title="New Legend Title")

```
````

Comment: Try changing the device to tikz using the chunk option `dev="tikz"`.

Comment: Martin, thank you!  Much better.  I hit 30 other threads on quality and no one mentioned tikz.  Worked first try.  I have much to learn about r, rmd, and latex.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to have higher quality plotting output when compiling to PDF is to use the tikz graphics device by setting the chunkk option `dev="tikz"` (or globally using `opts_chunk$set(dev = "tikz")`).

Tikz is a TeX package that allows to create vector graphics using an easy syntax. Using vector graphics has the advantage that they are scalable, annotations in your plot will use the same main font that is used in the document and you can easily add math symbols to your plot using the TeX syntax:

```
plot(..., main = "$\\bar{\\mu}$")
```